# Restart Apache Airflow managed by supervisor

Tags: airflow

## Overview

I updated Apache Airflow from 1.9.0 to 1.10.10. I'm managing the Airflow processes/components via supervisor. I have an ansible-playbook that restarts these processes every time I deploy changes to the server.

### The problem

This script was working fine with 1.9.5, but after the upgrade every time I upgrade the Airflow processes, it seems like lost the state of the tasks and DAGs. These on of the failure emails I will get after the restart

```
Exception:
Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?
```

### Configurations

#### supervisor conf

```
[program:airflow-webserver]
command = /home/airflow/airflow-dags/script/airflow-webserver.sh
directory = /home/airflow/
environment=HOME="/home/airflow",USER="airflow",PATH="{{ airflow_python_path }}:{{ airflow_venv_path }}/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
user = airflow
stdout_logfile = /var/log/airflow/webserver-logs.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/airflow/webserver-errors.log
stdout_logfile_backups = 0
redirect_stderr = true
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startretries = 3
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true

[program:airflow-scheduler]
command = /home/airflow/airflow-dags/script/airflow-scheduler.sh
directory = /home/airflow/
environment=HOME="/home/airflow",USER="airflow",PATH="{{ airflow_python_path }}:{{ airflow_venv_path }}/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
user = airflow
stdout_logfile = /var/log/airflow/scheduler-logs.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/airflow/scheduler-errors.log
stdout_logfile_backups = 0
redirect_stderr = true
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startretries = 3
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

[program:airflow-worker]
command = /home/airflow/airflow-dags/script/airflow-worker.sh
directory = /home/airflow/
environment=HOME="/home/airflow",USER="airflow",PATH="{{ airflow_python_path }}:{{ airflow_venv_path }}/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
user = airflow
stdout_logfile = /var/log/airflow/worker-logs.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/airflow/worker-errors.log
stdout_logfile_backups = 0
redirect_stderr = true
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startretries = 3
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

#### airflow-webserver.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/home/airflow/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
pyenv activate airflow-1_10
airflow webserver
```

#### airflow-workerd.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/home/airflow/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
pyenv activate airflow-1_10
airflow worker
```

#### airflow-scheduler.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/home/airflow/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
pyenv activate airflow-1_10
airflow scheduler
```

Comment: 1.9.5 isn't a valid Airflow version.....? It went from 1.9.0 to 1.10.10

Comment: What's in /var/log/airflow/worker-logs.log and /var/log/airflow/worker-errors.log?

Comment: What are in your `script/airflow-*.sh` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted the question on Airflow's Slack. I got a response that I don't need to restart the services. Airflow will read the new python DAG's files and refresh the information on the UI. So shot answer **I don't need to restart the services*